# Svelte: files imported through index.html are not building

Tags: javascript, html, web, svelte, svelte-3

I am building a Svelte app, where I have to reference some local `.js` files. I'm doing that like so (referencing then in index.html file):
[image]

All works just fine in dev preview, the issue appears when I try to build the project. Then all the references in index.html file stay the same but referenced files do not make it through build.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with either my importing process or project structure, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: This is a bundler issue but you omitted to mention which one you're using.
In the meanwhile, if it's a SPA try to nest those scripts  within <svelte:head> tags in your App.svelte. If you're using sveltekit, same but within +layout.svelte

Comment: @Tonton-Blax I am using Vite. I tried putting all the imports into <svelte:head>, but I am facing the same problem after build. My code is importing a js file from some location inside a project, which can not be found, because built project only has three files (html, css and  one js file).

Comment: Well are you sure they're not bundled into the output js? What happens when you try to ```console.log(WebMidi)``` ?
Also in your vite.config.js try to add:
```optimizeDeps: { exclude: ['the', 'list', 'of', 'your', 'dependencies']}```